# IBM Watson chatbot complex decision making

Tags: numbers, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am currently working to build an IBM Watson chatbot and I am running into 2 issues.

Overview: I am building a chatbot that asks questions about the user so the bot can then spit out a "decision" or solution based on how the user answers the questions. Ex. Q1:A Q2:B Q3:D Q4:A    CHat bot would spit out the responsibilities associated with collecting A,B,D,A. ABDA = Outcome 5 (out of 16)

Problem 1: Two of my questions lead to the user to input a number as their response. (asking for age and another question asks for years of experience) I do not know how to get Watson to know the difference between them without asking/prompting the user to add "years old" or "years Exp". Has anyone ran into issues of Watson not being able to handle numbers through multiple questions.

Problem 2: Anyone have any suggestions on how to get watson to digest all the questions asked then spit out the correct outcome?

Comment: You need to design the dialog and really prompt the user. When you would be asked about age, street number and number of kids, how would you answer? You can use the position in the input to assign based on that information, but....

Comment: I currently have it set up as a line of questioning, as in, the chatbot recognizing a "correct" answer to spur the next question to ask to gather data. Would you suggest another of building out the questions?

Comment: What would be a natural flow for you as user?